# How to write the css in order the image goes under the sticky horizontal navbar?

Tags: navbar, amp-html, sticky

For the text, when I scroll down, the text goes under the sticky navbar. 
[image]

But for image, when I scroll down, the image is in front of the sticky navbar.
[image]

I've tried to look on the internet, but I can't find the one within amp-html.

Here is the code I get from the internet

```
    <!doctype html>
<html amp>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TEST STICKY NAVBAR</title>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.indonesiangems.com">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
    <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

<style amp-custom>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
 font-size: 17px;
}

a {text-decoration: none;}

.container{
max-width: 800px;
margin: auto;
 }

p,h3{
margin:auto;
  padding : 10px;  
text-align: justify;
}

  .center {
    text-align: center;
    font-style: italic;
  }

  .footer {
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
    }
        
div.scrollmenu {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
font-size: 14px;
}

div.scrollmenu a:hover {
  background-color: #777;
}

div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="sticky">
<amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x400/000/fff" 
         width="1200" height="400" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
<div align="center">
<div class="scrollmenu">
   <a href="#">bla bla bla</a> 
   <a href="#">blublublublu</a>
   <a href="#">belbelbelbe</a>
   <a href="#">blobloblboblo</a>
   <a href="#">blibliblibli</a> 
</div>
</div>
</div>

  <h3>Test</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc </p>

<div class="center">
<amp-img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x260/22d91c/fff"
         width="320" height="260" layout="responsive"></amp-img><br>
        Variety of Indonesian gemstones
</div>
    
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec </p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum,

Comment: Give z-index some positive value to your sticky div

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh, wow... thank you very much, Muhammad.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the z-index property in your image.

Add this to your CSS file.

```
.center amp-img
{
z-index: -1;

}
```

Comment: Besides as Muhammad answer in his comment, this one also work. Thank you, Mohit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how essential it is for that image to have an  tag, but a quick fix is to turn the  tag to a regular  tag like I did below.

```
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/320x260/22d91c/fff"
     width="320" height="260" max-width="320"></img><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, spd75. I also don't know why the amp-html rule need to use `amp-img` tag. Long time ago, in the amp html I just wrote like your suggestion, but then when I validate the amp code, it complaint saying that I have to put that `amp-img` tag. Anyway, thank you once again for your answer.